# How to reduce inode usage when there are only 6 files

Tags: macos, filesystem

I am trying to clear the inode usage on my thumb drive on a Mac 11.7. It has plenty of memory, but the `ifree` is 0.

I followed the advice in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9387415), but there are only a handful of files left. I have cleared out everything in the Trash, but still I cannot liberate the inodes. I can't add anything to the drive until there are more inodes available.

The `.Trashes` directory, where there is "Operation not permitted", is empty, according to the Mac Finder.

```
(base) j-ml3:TRAVELDRIVE jchavez$ df -h .
Filesystem     Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused ifree %iused  Mounted on
/[redacted]  984Mi  832Ki  983Mi     1%     512     0  100%   /Volumes/TRAVELDRIVE
(base) j-ml3:TRAVELDRIVE jchavez$ sudo find . -xdev -type f | cut -d "/" -f 2 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
Password:
find: ./.Trashes: Operation not permitted
   1 .DS_Store
   1 ._.Trashes
   1 .fseventsd
   1 fitshead
   1 ratiodifferences.sxc
   1 rollover
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just copy the content back to the main drive, reformat the USB stick, and then move the data back onto the stick.

If you are unsure about the quality of the stick (or are worried about failing), it might also be a good moment to back up the content.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. The details to do the reformatting are here, https://support.apple.com/guide/disk-utility/erase-and-reformat-a-storage-device-dskutl14079/20.0/mac/11.0. 
Select the appropriate Operating System version from the drop-down at the top to get the correct instructions.